# Convert an object into another type of object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I want to convert the object which I am getting from a function into the NoSql database format.

I have an object like this:

```
{
"visible": true,
"active": true,
"invalidated": true,
"handles": {
    "start": {
        "x": 2094.803738317757,
        "y": 2038.5794392523367,
        "highlight": true,
        "active": false
    },
    "end": {
        "x": 2487.1775700934586,
        "y": 2555.364485981309,
        "highlight": true,
        "active": false,
        "moving": false
    },
    "initialRotation": 0,
}
}
```

I created the NoSQL databases like the below one and now want to convert the above object into an object like this:

```
"visible": {
 "BOOL": true
},
"active": {
 "BOOL": true
},
"handles": {
"M": {
    "end": {
        "M": {
            "active": {
                "BOOL": false
            },
            "highlight": {
                "BOOL": true
            },
            "moving": {
                "BOOL": false
            },
            "x": {
                "N": "2487"
            },
            "y": {
                "N": "2555"
            }
        }
    },
    "initialRotation": {
        "N": "0"
    },
    "start": {
        "M": {
            "active": {
                "BOOL": false
            },
            "highlight": {
                "BOOL": true
            },
            "x": {
                "N": "2094"
            },
            "y": {
                "N": "2038"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I cannot find a way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Is there anything wrong with the simplest function, in that use case? I made some assumptions based of the object you provided as an example: that you are flooring the coordinate numbers, and you want them as a string in the new object.

```
const convertObj = (obj) => {
return {
  visible: {
    BOOL: obj.visible,
  },
  active: {
    BOOL: obj.active,
  },
  handles: {
    M: {
      end: {
        M: {
          active: {
            BOOL: obj.handles.end.active,
          },
          highlight: {
            BOOL: obj.handles.end.highlight,
          },
          moving: {
            BOOL: obj.handles.end.moving,
          },
          x: {
            N: Math.floor(obj.handles.end.x).toString(),
          },
          y: {
            N: Math.floor(obj.handles.end.y).toString(),
          },
        },
      },
      initialRotation: {
        N: obj.handles.initialRotation.toString(),
      },
      start: {
        M: {
          active: {
            BOOL: obj.handles.start.active,
          },
          highlight: {
            BOOL: obj.handles.start.highlight,
          },
          x: {
            N: Math.floor(obj.handles.start.x).toString(),
          },
          y: {
            N: Math.floor(obj.handles.start.y).toString(),
          },
        },
      },
    },
  },
};
```

};